# How to clear datalist input on click?

Tags: javascript, onclick, lit-element, onfocus, html-datalist

I have this datalist inside a Lit-Element web component:

```
<input list="cars" name="car" placeholder = "Type car name">

<datalist id="cars">
  <option value="Jeep">
  <option value="Lamborghini">
  <option value="Ferrari">
  <option value="Fiat 500">
  <option value="Gran Torino">
</datalist>
```

If I select one of these options from the list, and then I click again on input field, I can't see the list of option but only the selected one. If I want to see all the options I have to manually delete with the keyboard the option written on input field.

Does it exist a way to show all the options even if one of these options is selected?

Or better, does it exist a way to clear the input field on focus or on click?

Without JQuery.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Create `onfocus` and `onchange` listeners on your `input` element to clear focus after selecting an option, then clear input on focus.

```html
<input list="cars" name="car" onfocus="this.value=''" onchange="this.blur();" placeholder = "Type car name">

<datalist id="cars">
  <option value="Jeep">
  <option value="Lamborghini">
  <option value="Ferrari">
  <option value="Fiat 500">
  <option value="Gran Torino">
</datalist>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you

Comment: This solution is excellent! Any idea how to get it working inside a React controlled component? When I clear the value in a my onChange handler, it takes a second click to populate the datalist with all the unfiltered options.

Comment: In case it's useful to anyone else, Alfred replied to my question about solving this problem inside a React component on my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65574573/clear-datalist-input-onclick-in-react-controlled-component/65574929?noredirect=1#comment115957811_65574929

Comment: Great ! I was getting mad about it :( element`.blur()` works perfectly, many thanks for this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can clear a field by clicking on it but I'd recommend to only select it on click and not delete it directly since a miss click could happen.

```js
    YOUR_ELEMENT.addEventListener('click', mouse_event =>{
        mouse_event.target.select() 
    });
```

```js
    YOUR_ELEMENT.addEventListener('click', mouse_event =>{
        mouse_event.target.value = '' 
    });
```

check the snippet

```js
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.target.value = ''
})
document.getElementById('test2').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.target.select()
})
```

```html
<input type='text' id='test' placeholder='delete'/>
<input type='text' id='test2' placeholder='select'/>
```